# symbolic link : confused about what it creates

Tags: symlink

I am confused about the command "ln -s".
When I do:

```
sudo ln -s /projects/MyProject ~/project1/code
```

This creates a "MyProject" folder link inside my "~/project1/code" folder.

I was hoping to have the same content on /projects/MyProject and ~/project1/code, not finding a subfolder "Myproject".

Can I do what I want with ln -s or should I look at something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A symbolic link is effectively a pointer to some other file.  It is not entirely clear what you want, but the following will create a symbolic link called `MyProject` in the `~/project1` directory:

```
sudo ln -s /projects/MyProject ~/project1/
```

That is, there will exist a directory `~/project1/MyProject` that contains all the same files as in `/projects/MyProject`.  If you update or add files to `~/project1/MyProject`, they will be updated or added to `/projects/MyProject`.

Alternatively, if you want to keep track of *just* the files in `/projects/MyProject`, then you can do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /projects/MyProject/* ~/project1/code`
```

This will create the directory `~/project1/code` which will contain symbolic links to all the files in `/projects/MyProject`.  New files added to `~/project1/code` will not be added to `projects/MyProject`, however.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, if you go into the `~/project1` directory and then type

```
sudo ln -s /projects/MyProject code
```

then that will create a symbolic link called `code` in the `~/project1` directory, which is itself a link to `/projects/MyProject`.

Comment: Ok I see so I cannot choose the name of the link and have ~/project1/code linked to /projects/MyProject right?